How to add sidebar to taxonomy template Wordpress
I am working on a WordPress website, using a theme.
I have a page "Careers", that shows all the careers on the right side, and on the left side  there is the sidebar "sidebar_widgets" with some filtering options.

Now when I click on some filtering option, let's say "Full-Time", I am being automatically redirected to the link /career-career-tag/full-time. This I assume is the taxonomy page, and it correctly shows me only the careers that have the tag full-time.

The problem now is, that the sidebar with the filtering widgets is no longer shown, and I cannot filter further. This page I think is some kind of default WordPress page, not visible in the "Pages" section of wp-admin.
Upon looking into the code, I found that this taxonomy page uses the code from index.php, which is the most generic template.
Now I have created a file called taxonomy.php, in order to edit the template and to include the sidebar, but I don't know what to put inside.
The index.php contains this code:
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage AUTOPARTS
 * @since AUTOPARTS 1.0
 */
if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'classic' )
    get_template_part( 'index', 'classic' );
else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'masonry' )
    get_template_part( 'index', 'classic' );
else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'gallery' )
    get_template_part( 'index', 'portfolio' );
else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 9) == 'portfolio' )
    get_template_part( 'index', 'portfolio' );
else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 5) == 'chess' )
    get_template_part( 'index', 'chess' );
else
    get_template_part( 'index', 'excerpt' );
?>

How to edit this? Or what do i need to add in the taxonomy.php in order to add the sidebar, and the sidebar widgets?
UPDATE
So I've used the tutorial here: and I have added this:
function taxonomy_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Taxonomy sidebar',
    'id' => 'taxonomy_sidebar',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'taxonomy_widgets_init' );

and in my taxonomy.php:
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying taxonomy archive pages.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage AUTOPARTS
 * @since AUTOPARTS 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <main class="main-content">
        <?php
        
            if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'classic' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'classic' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'masonry' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'classic' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'gallery' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'portfolio' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 9) == 'portfolio' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'portfolio' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 5) == 'chess' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'chess' );
            else
                get_template_part( 'index', 'excerpt' ); 
        ?>
    </main>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'taxonomy_sidebar' ); ?>
    </aside>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>


I can see the sidebar in WordPress and I have added the widgets that I want. Just, when I run the page, I get these errors:

UPDATE 2
So apparently the errors were cause because of the <aside>(I think so).
If I use:
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying taxonomy archive pages.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage AUTOPARTS
 * @since AUTOPARTS 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <main class="main-content">
        <?php

            if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'classic' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'classic' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'masonry' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'classic' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 7) == 'gallery' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'portfolio' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 9) == 'portfolio' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'portfolio' );
            else if ( substr(autoparts_get_theme_option('blog_style'), 0, 5) == 'chess' )
                get_template_part( 'index', 'chess' );
            else
                get_template_part( 'index', 'excerpt' ); 
        ?>
    </main>
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'taxonomy_sidebar' ) ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'taxonomy_sidebar' ); endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

The page runs without errors in the console. But the problem is that the sidebar is placed at the end of the page, and not in the content.  How can I edit the template so I place it in the correct place?


"How can I edit the template so I place it in the correct place?" - <aside class="sidebar"> most likely is the correct location already, because surely your theme will be set up to show that element as a left column, when it is present. What might be causing those JavaScript errors, is hard to say, without knowing details about the widget.

Well, my widget is of type "List Custom Taxonomy". I don't think it has to do with the js errors. My guess is that's not the way to add it. I am guessing there should be some other template or way to edit the template in order to place in in the page content. I don't know though..

The JS errors are referring to autoparts_fix_sidebar, so presumably they do have something to do with the existence of a sidebar element on that page. What does the HTML structure look like on your initial Careers page?

At first, the taxonomy_sidebar is not wrapped by any DIV, so it appears below the footer, wrap it with a  use display-flex in the content-wrapper class or float-left in the taxonomy class, adjusting the size of each div so that they appear side by side.
